# Converting kafka message into Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apache-kafka

I have kafka consumer trying to read messages from kafka broker and convert it into pandas dataframe :
here is my message value :

```
message.value= {'class': '3rd',  'Year': '2022',  'Students': '16',  'Degree': 'computer science'}
```

This message is of type str so when I try to convert it into pandas dataframe using the next code:

```
s = str(message.value, 'utf-8')
data = StringIO(s)
df = pd.read_csv(data)
```

I got as output:

```
 Empty DataFrame
 Columns: [{'class': '3rd',  'Year': '2022',  'Students': '16',  'Degree': 'computer science'}]
 Index: []
```

Also, I have tried the next solution but it is the same thing:

```
df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(message.value))
```

Comment: Isn't your `message.value` a dictionary? You can create a dataframe from a dictionary: `pd.DataFrame(message.value)`.

Comment: Better question is why do you need this? Each dataframe would only be one row. If you want a batch of messages, you can use pyspark structured streaming

Comment: At the end I want to concatenate the data frames to calculate the number of student in total so I will use groupby

Comment: @ibmx, it is the same I could not convert this dict to data frame

Comment: Here the error I got:

'ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!'

Comment: It's actually [`Dataframe.from_dict(message.value)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html). But you can just append dict types directly to a dataframe; you don't need to make every event its own https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html  And again, Structured Streaming in pyspark will do this for you